# File array initialization Error :Variable might not be initialized

Tags: java, file, directory

- In this function,I am trying to copy file from one location to
  another specified location where specific folder will created and
  pattern matching files will be copied to that single folder.

  ```
  public static void matchFileNames(List filesList,List fileTest){
                          String inputVal;
                          File[] tempDir; 
                          String tempFileName;
                          int l=0;
                          for (int i=0;i<filesList.size();i++){
                                  inputVal=filesList.get(i).toString();
                                      for(int k=0;k<fileTest.size();k++){
                                      String fileName=fileTest.get(k).toString();
                                          if (isMatching(fileName,inputVal)){
                                              tempFileName="D:\\Mass\\Dest"+"\\"+inputVal;
                                          try {
                                              tempDir[l]=new File(tempFileName);
                                              if(l==0){
                                                  tempDir[l++].mkdir();
                                                  copyFileContents(new File("D:\\Mass\\Auto"+"\\"+fileName+".txt"),new File("D:\\Mass\\Dest"+"\\"+tempFileName+"\\"+fileName+".txt"));
                                              }
                                              if (!tempDir[l].exists()){
                                                  tempDir[l++].mkdir();
                                                  copyFileContents(new File("D:\\Mass\\Auto"+"\\"+fileName+".txt"),new File("D:\\Mass\\Dest"+"\\"+tempFileName+"\\"+fileName+".txt"));
                                              }
                                              else
                                                  copyFileContents(new File("D:\\Mass\\Auto"+"\\"+fileName+".txt"),new File("D:\\Mass\\Dest"+"\\"+tempFileName+"\\"+fileName+".txt"));
                                          }catch (Exception x) {
                                              x.printStackTrace();
                                          }
                                          }   
                                      }   
                              }
                          }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As per [JLS rule of definite assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html), local variables need to be intiailized and hence the error. So intialize your `inputVal` and `tempFileName` variables. May be like this:

```
   String inputVal = ""; // or with null or any other apt value
   File[] tempDir=null; 
   String tempFileName = ""; // or will null or any other apt value
```

Comment: After initializing as directed,"Null Pointer exception" is arising.